Blazor .Net Core 8: How to use Server Side Component on the Client side?
I want to use the InteractiveAuto feature of WASM. So I want to create my pages on the client side.
But I also want to access server side components that have access to my SQL database.
It seems though only the server project can access the server components.
I tried to @inject in the _imports file, but that did not work.
I also tried to reference the Server Project in the Client Project, but I receive an error of circularity.


Because the server project has dependency on client project already. So you couldn't let client project reference server again.

Best way is put all components in the client side.
Then if you set this component rendermode to Interactive Server or SSR, it will still run on server side project.
Only when you set this component render mode to WASM or Auto, it will run using client side project.

Thank you I will give it a shot and update afterwards.
My components access a SQL database and I was under the assumption I had to put components on the Server side if I did not want the client to get all the passwords and so on.
It will probably be next week before I can update, but I will!!!

@sTaLa: Components that use SQL will not work on the Client anyway.
